# How to deploy a php website with gitlab ci

Tags: php, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab

I started using gitlab ci recently, until now i am able to run a simple job who is executed by a specific runner(like doc generation ...)

As I'm new to this, I have some questions on how to deploy a simple PHP project (still on local). When i take a look on the doc I can't understand the steps of  how the deploy job process works( push the database on the server)

Comment: You wouldn't want to deploy your DEV-database to your LIVE server, fields get overwritten etc. Keep them separated and use CI for code.

Comment: dont push database, use migrations for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so i only got to focus on my deployment job.

This one will consist on : 1-create a user who will deploy
                                       2- generate ssh keys on the server
                                       3- include this to my gitlab ci file
  environment:
    name: prod
    url: my server url
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to production server" // is there a simple example on what to have in this part, I am a little bit confused on what i found on the doc 
  only:
    - master

Comment: Hi Nou, I'm not familiar with gitlab-ci but if you couldn't make it work I'd suggest you to give Deploybot a try. On their documentation they have guidelines about setting up the deployment process. Deploybot is the one I have experience with but you can find other great similar tools as well :)